# How to insert JSON Array into database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, json

I'm using dropdown when selected first dropdown, based on first dropdown selected it will show second dropdown. Each dropdown have data from database and the problem is i want to insert it into new table on database based on dropdown selected.

All the code on the same page, this is the php.

```
<?php
            $sql= mysql_query("SELECT KodeMapel,NamaTema FROM mapel");
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
            {
                $tema[] = array("KodeMapel" => $row['KodeMapel'], "val" => $row['NamaTema']);
            }

            $query = mysql_query("SELECT KodeMapel, Subtema FROM subtema");

            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
            {
                $subtema[$row['KodeMapel']][] = array("KodeMapel" => $row['KodeMapel'], "val" => $row['Subtema']);
            }

            $jsonTema = json_encode($tema);
            $jsonSubTema = json_encode($subtema);
        ?>
```

This is the form, included javascript on it. Inside the javascript there's php code.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  <?php
    echo "var tema = $jsonTema;";
    echo "var subtema = $jsonSubTema;";
  ?>
  function loadtema(){
    var select = document.getElementById("PilihTema");
    select.onchange = updateSubTema;
    for(var i = 0; i < tema.length; i++){
      select.options[i] = new Option(tema[i].val,tema[i].KodeMapel);          
    }
  }
  function updateSubTema(){
    var PilihTema = this;
    var idtema = this.value;
    var PilihSubtema = document.getElementById("PilihSubtema");
    PilihSubtema.options.length = 0; //delete all options if any present
    for(var i = 0; i < subtema[idtema].length; i++){
      PilihSubtema.options[i] = new Option(subtema[idtema][i].val,subtema[idtema][i].KodeMapel);
    }
  }
</script>
<body onload='loadtema()'>
<select id='PilihTema' name='PilihTema' class='form-control11'>
</select>

<select id='PilihSubtema' name='PilihSubtema' class='form-control11'>
</select>
<button input class="btn btn-success" id="submit" type="submit" name="add" value="Simpan" onclick="return(submitmapel());"/>
    <i class="fa fa-save fa-fw"></i> Simpan
```

Answer (score 0):

So far I see some errors in your code.

```
select.onchange = updateSubTema;
```

You are missing () for the function. Should be `select.onchange = updateSubTema();`

I'm not sure if `var PilihTema = this;` will actually select anything, personally i'd do it the following way.

loadTema function:

```
var select = document.getElementById("PilihTema");
select.onchange = updateSubTema(select.value);
```

updateTema function

```
function updateTema(pilihTema){
  //Your code here
}
```

EDIT: If you mean you want to add an item per run through your `for` loop, I would suggest doing it the following way (I use jQuery as it is much easier in my opinion):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  <?php
    echo "var tema = $jsonTema;";
    echo "var subtema = $jsonSubTema;";
  ?>

  //Load Tema
  $.each(tema, function (i, item) {
  //I am unsure as to what you mean by KodeMapel, though if this is associative arrays encoded as JSON, you will want to use item[val] and item[KodeMapel]
    $("#PilihTema").append(new Option(item.val, item.KodeMapel));
  });

  //Called when the first select field is changed.
  $("#PilihTema").change(function(){
    //Get value of first select fields' selected item
    var pilihValue = $("#PilihTema option:checked").val();

    //Remove all the options from the second select field
    $("#PilihSubtema").html(""); 

    //For each subtema, with first select fields value, add option to second select field
    $.each(subtema[pilihValue], function (i, item) {
      //Again, I am unsure as to what you mean by KodeMapel, though if this is associative arrays encoded as JSON, you will want to use item[val] and item[KodeMapel]
      $("#PilihSubtema").append(new Option(item.val, item.KodeMapel));
    });

  });

});
```

Comment: @skobaljic okay, no worries, removed. Didn't think that actually worked.

Comment: thank you for replied. when i try to add () and remove var this, the combobox display nothing.

Comment: @graybullet171 By combobox, do you mean the select dropdown?